# "[BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined" error in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm getting this error:

```
[BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined
```

Code:

```
const client = new Client({ 
intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.GUILD_VOICE_STATES] 
});
```

Comment: Typo, it should be `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from **Zsolt Meszaros**

It should be `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES` instead of `Intents.GUILDS_VOICE_STATE`.

You can also set Intents via strings instead of `Intents.FLAGS` object.

```js
const client = new Client({ 
  intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES"] 
});
```